# jQuery: click function and ajaxy plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I am using balupton ajaxy plugin.

I am trying to add a class on an element with on("click") function but due to the ajaxy plugin that handles the click function on the specific element , it doesn't work.

I have this list:

```
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="company.html" class="ajaxy ajaxy-page"> company</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="aboutus.html" class="ajaxy ajaxy-page">aboutus</a></li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html" class="ajaxy ajaxy-page">contactus</a></li>
      </ul>  
      </li>
   <li><a href="services.html" class="ajaxy ajaxy-page">services</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this, and it works for the "li" but not for the "a" element.

```
$(".menu li").on("click", function(){
  alert("aa");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? please post your code, or better yet, make a JSFiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

I would put your new click handler outside of the plugin code, probably after it.

```
//Plugin code here
// $(".menu li").click(function(){
  alert("aa");
 });
```

Alternatively, you could explore if the AJAXY plugin offers a callback feature?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this if you want the LI and also the A to respond:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".menu li,.menu a").on("click", function(){
    alert("aa");
  });
});
```

And do not forget to call it in document ready, so that it is inicilazed after the plugin is.